# DateTime.now not setting timezone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

I have a column called "Archived" in my message table and a button that when pushed will write the current time and date into the db column. Right now I can get it to write the time, however it's in the wrong timezone. After looking online I created the following code which is currently saving, but not in the correct timezone:

Controller Code

```
def archive_message
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  @message.archived = DateTime.now.in_time_zone "Central Time (US & Canada)"
  @message.save

  redirect_to '/messages'
end
```

My route (I believe this is ok as is)

```
post 'messages/:id/archive_message' => 'Messages#archive_message', :as => 'archive_message'
```

Any suggestions are well appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a zoneinfo ID, e.g. America/Chicago? Just for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: I tried     `code` @message.archived = DateTime.now.in_time_zone "America/Chicago"
and is did the same thing as
    `code` @message.archived = DateTime.now.in_time_zone "Central Time (US & Canada)"

Comment: Someone posted to add
    config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
to my application.rb file. I added this to my module code and it seems to have completely changed the date and time, now it is showing the time as being tomorrow.

Comment: DateTime.current should return the time in the app specified timezone.

Comment: I tried DateTime.current in my controller and it setting it 5 hours ahead of what it should. This is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT AGAIN: OK this is UTC time, so it's working. Thank you everyone.

EDIT: I just closed an restarted everything and now it is NOT WORKING, it is saving the time as 5 hours ahead again and I have no idea why.

In config/application.rb
added the following to module code

> ```
> config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
> config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
> ```

and my controller

> ```
> @message.archived = DateTime.current
> ```

thanks everyone